# ANTLR Plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, antlr

sorry for my english! I install plagin in eclipse, but wen i run my little project i have this problem. Why its not work?

> error(10):  internal error: Can't get property indirectDelegates using
>   method get/isIndirectDelegates from org.antlr.tool.Grammar instance :
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>   java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Unknown Source)
>   java.util.ArrayList.removeAll(Unknown Source)
>   org.antlr.tool.CompositeGrammar.getIndirectDelegates(CompositeGrammar.java:222)
>   org.antlr.tool.Grammar.getIndirectDelegates(Grammar.java:2620)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.ASTExpr.invokeMethod(ASTExpr.java:564)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.ASTExpr.rawGetObjectProperty(ASTExpr.java:515)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.ASTExpr.getObjectProperty(ASTExpr.java:417)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.ActionEvaluator.attribute(ActionEvaluator.java:351)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.ActionEvaluator.expr(ActionEvaluator.java:136)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.ActionEvaluator.templateApplication(ActionEvaluator.java:216)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.ActionEvaluator.expr(ActionEvaluator.java:126)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.ActionEvaluator.action(ActionEvaluator.java:84)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.ASTExpr.write(ASTExpr.java:149)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate.write(StringTemplate.java:705)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.ASTExpr.writeTemplate(ASTExpr.java:750)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.ASTExpr.write(ASTExpr.java:680)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.ASTExpr.writeAttribute(ASTExpr.java:660)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.ActionEvaluator.action(ActionEvaluator.java:86)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.ASTExpr.write(ASTExpr.java:149)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate.write(StringTemplate.java:705)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.ASTExpr.writeTemplate(ASTExpr.java:750)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.ASTExpr.write(ASTExpr.java:680)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.ASTExpr.writeAttribute(ASTExpr.java:660)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.ActionEvaluator.action(ActionEvaluator.java:86)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.ASTExpr.write(ASTExpr.java:149)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate.write(StringTemplate.java:705)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.ASTExpr.writeTemplate(ASTExpr.java:750)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.ASTExpr.write(ASTExpr.java:680)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.ASTExpr.writeAttribute(ASTExpr.java:660)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.ActionEvaluator.action(ActionEvaluator.java:86)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.ASTExpr.write(ASTExpr.java:149)
>   org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate.write(StringTemplate.java:705)
>   org.antlr.codegen.CodeGenerator.write(CodeGenerator.java:1281)
>   org.antlr.codegen.Target.genRecognizerFile(Target.java:94)
>   org.antlr.codegen.CodeGenerator.genRecognizer(CodeGenerator.java:466)
>   org.antlr.Tool.generateRecognizer(Tool.java:641)
>   org.antlr.Tool.process(Tool.java:454)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

ANTLR 3 produces this message when used with Java 8. However, it doesn't seem to affect the actual output. Until the fix is released in a new version of ANTLR 3, you can either ignore the message, or use Java 7.

Related issue:
[#151: NPE in CompositeGrammer.getIndirectDelegates in Java 8](https://github.com/antlr/antlr3/issues/151)

Comment: Thanks a lot Harwell, I have the same problem even if it has correctly created the lexer and parser classes, but I have Build Failure.

Is it because of this ignore we can ignore that I have Build Failure ?

Comment: My build started to fail. I had Java 8 Update 39. Updated to Java 8 Update 40. Still didn't help. So, had to revert back to Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error running ANTLR 3.1.1 with Java 1.8. In my Ant Build file, I changed the attribute of the "java" task to "failonerror="false". I still got the error message, but my build stopped failing and produced the output that I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

For java 8 and antlr 3, change the jar to "antlr-3.5.2-complete.jar" and the error will go away.

1. update the ANTLR plugin to version 2.1.2
2. Go to project properties-> ANTLR -> Building
3. Uncheck "Enable project specific settings"
4. Click "Configure Workspace Settings" -> ANTLR -> Builder -> Building
5. Remove the installed 3.5.2 package
6. Add installed packages and point it to the folder of "antlr-3.5.2-complete.jar"
7. Save and come back to enable project specific settings.
8. In the General-> ANTLR Runtime, select 3.5.2